# How to run a Package (not a class) using UiAutomator?

Tags: java, android, package, android-uiautomator

I have my code sorted in Packages ('first' and 'second') using UiAutomator and Java.

To run a class the command is `adb shell uiautomator runtest MyProject.jar -c first.MyClass1`
But I have a lot of classes in 'first' package, so, I need to run test by Package. I have tried using `adb shell uiautomator runtest MyProject.jar -c first` but -c command is only for Classes. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

For **API >= 18**, `-c` argument is not required and if not specified, all test cases in `<JARS>` will be run.
Then, if you don't want to run them all, just split into different `<JARS>` per package.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to trying automation tool ,you can use [UiAutomator-bot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uiautomator). As the test cases in uiautomator-bot are organised as test suites, you can select individual test suites/cases for execution.Further, you can generate execution reports,screenshots and logs. For more info refer this [link](http://uiautomator-bot.blogspot.com)

Answer (score 0):

This is my temporary solution. If someone has a better and fancy solution, please share it.

```
SET directory=first
cd %directory%
for /r . %%i in (*.class) do adb shell uiautomator runtest AutosanityL.jar -c %directory%.%%~ni
cd ..
pause
```